# Regular Expression to parse command lines

Tags: c#, regex

I need a Regular Expression to parse commands such as:

> C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe https:\www.google.com
>   C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe http:\www.google.com
>   C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe www.google.com
>   iexplore.exe https:\www.google.com 
>   copy C:\test.txt D:\

The point is that I want to get the first part as command and the other parts as arguments. Commands can be anything including `.bat`, `.vbs`, `.exe` etc.

Found a Regular Expression which is working normally if there is no space in command.

```
string str = @"C:\xcopy D:\test.txt D:\Test";

string pattern = @"^(?:""([^""]*)""\s*|([^""\s]+)\s*)+";        
Regex parseDir = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if(parseDir.IsMatch(str))
{
    Match dir = parseDir.Match(str);
    var captures = dir.Groups[1].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Concat(
       dir.Groups[2].Captures.Cast<Capture>()).
       OrderBy(x => x.Index).
       ToArray();
    string cmd = captures[0].Value;
    string arguments = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 1; i < captures.Length; i++)
    {
        arguments += captures[i].Value + " ";    
    }
    Console.WriteLine(cmd);
    Console.WriteLine(arguments);
}
```

Comment: Are the commands in a string that you're trying to parse (from user-input, a file, etc), or are they literally command-line parameters that are passed when initializing your application?

Comment: Yes it's a string that I need to parse the problem is that in command can be a space(s) and I cannot split it by space.

Comment: May you please post an output example that describes how this will work? :)

Comment: I need some regular expression that will try to parse directory or URL but it must be the first part of command

Comment: (^[a-zA-Z]:\\[^/:\*;\/\:\?<>\|]+\s)|(^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\s)|(^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+$)|(^[a-zA-Z0-9]\.+[a-zA-Z]+\s)|(^(http|https|ftp)\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*[^\.\,\)\(\s]+\s)|(^(http|https|ftp)\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*[^\.\,\)\(\s]+$)                         this regexp is just separating command so after I can replace command and get args

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a standard Console application, the main entry point args[] will already have parsed this for you. There's a caveat here, because the examples you've provided won't work because of the spaces in them (C:\Program Files) but if you surround them with quotes ("C:\Program Files\Internet ...\iexplorer.exe") you'll find this works correctly.

This [link walks you through creating a console application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wc2kk78%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

**UPDATE:**

Well then, if it's not a console application but you'd like to simulate exactly what the Console Application start-up routine provides you, may I introduce to you the one and only *CommandLineToArgvW* native method.

```
    [DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr CommandLineToArgvW(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpCmdLine, 
        out int pNumArgs);
```

This ridiculously simple method takes any string and converts it into an array. Here's a utility class that you can use to convert your text input into a well formed array.

```
    /// <summary>
/// Wrapper class for Win32 API calls
/// </summary>
public class NativeMethods
{

    [DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr CommandLineToArgvW(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpCmdLine, out int pNumArgs);

    /// <summary>
    /// Parse a string into an array, including items in quotes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="commandLine"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string[] CommandLineToArgs(string commandLine)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(commandLine))
            return new string[] {};

        int argc;
        var argv = CommandLineToArgvW(commandLine, out argc);
        if (argv == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
        try
        {
            var args = new string[argc];
            for (var i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
            {
                var p = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(argv, i * IntPtr.Size);
                args[i] = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(p);
            }

            return args;
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(argv);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No it's not console app with args there is text box where I can paste command with args and I need to parse it in order to separate command and args and send them for execution.

Comment: Actually I don't want to parse just arguments I want to parse hole string where are the command with arguments let me explain what I have and what I need I have developed client server app where server can send commands to multiple clients for execution and command is just a string I need to parse the point is that I want to just separate the command I don't care about how many args there for example there can be C:\test.exe arg0 arg1 ... or test.exe arg0 arg1 .. or C:\program files\test.exe arg0 arg1 ... what I need in this case just parse and get command (test.exe or C:\test.exe or ...)

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I'm assuming you are looking for a way to pass batch commands in a text on the Windows OS. The only way I can think of for you to do this successfully is if you have a list of all the commands or if your program can extract all the .exe files in the system, that way you can successfully check where the first exe file *which is the target program of the command* is and assume the others as arguments.

This way, you can do your extraction like this (Non-regex method):

```
var cmd = "copy this.txt C:\t.txt"
var program = getTargetProgram(cmd);
var args = cmd.Substring(cmd.IndexOf(program) + program.length).trim().split(' ');
```

your `getTargetProgram()` could go like this:

```
private string getTargetProgram(string cmd)
{
    //first test if it's a normal executable
    if(File.Exists(cmd.Substring(0, cmd.IndexOf(".exe") + 4)) //return this extract;
    foreach(string s in winProgramList)
    {
       if(cmd.StartsWith(s)){
             //voila, we can return the target
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: in this case I need to have list of programs and also type of programs because command will not be only .exe files

Comment: exactly, you can usually get them by typing help in the Command Prompt window or just extracting all *.exe* from your system directory, i.e. `Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Windows\system32", *.exe);`

Answer (score 0):

You either need to put quotes around the program path/name (if it has spaces in it), or write some extra code to figure out the program part of it.

One approach that comes to mind is to start with the first capture (for your `iexplorer.exe` example, it would be `C:\Program`), check if it's a valid program. If not, add the next capture with a space (e.g., `C:\Program` + `Files\Internet` => `C:\Program Files\Internet`) and repeat the check. Repeat until you've run out of captures or have found a valid program, and treat the rest as arguments normally.

No reason to do the parsing manually, as another answer suggested. The regexes will still work.